# Searching a log file using PHP from input pattern

Tags: php, search

My problem is to create a search function that can search within a log file.

The pattern is something like this:

```
node-id > command
-Date-other descriptions
Output starts
Output ends
node-id > another command
```

Now, the problem I have is to cut the output of one command from one log file and compare it with the output from another log file for comparison. I am not able to find a way to search the content and store it into an array or file for further comparison.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What errors or problems are you getting with what you have tried? Please provide some code and indication of your idea for solving this.

Answer (score 0):

You can't cut stuff from a file, you can only change the file and re-save it (you could potentially cut stuff, depending on your file system, directly manipulating the same, but asking this question here means you don't have such low-level file system experience)

In php it would be something like:

```
$data = file_get_contents($fileToCutFrom);
// ... modify data here, e.g. if it's xml you might wanna use SimpleXML or DOMDocument or some other xml parser, like ganon ( https://code.google.com/p/ganon/ ) - the later one is pretty good if you know you might have incomplete/invalid xml
file_put_contents($fileToCutFrom, $modifiedData);


// and now append to the other file
file_put_contents($fileToAppendTo, $dataToAppend, FILE_APPEND);
```

Know however that you might get into serious race conditions if you do this from more than one file, as file_get_contents is not atomic, and neither is file_put_contents, and then you also have the problem of having multiple lines to execute. So if your code might get executed several times at once, you might wanna use a single script instance which does all the "cutting" and appending opening up a socket and the other scripts just send what they need to that file.

Also, if you wanna continuesly do that whenver new data comes in, you might wanna have a look at inotify (linux) or the equivalent on your system (osx also has a file notification service, but I don't know about windows)

If you need something different, you might wanna add information to your question.